# ruby 1.9 wrong file encoding on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding

I have a ruby file with these contents:

```
# encoding: iso-8859-1
File.open('foo.txt', "w:iso-8859-1") {|f| f << 'fòo'}
puts File.read('foo.txt').encoding
```

- When I run it from windows command prompt ruby 1.9.3 I get: IBM437
- When I run it from cygwin ruby 1.9.3 I get: UTF-8
- What I expect to get is: iso-8859-1

Can someone explain what's happening here?

**UPDATE**

Here's a better description of what I'm looking for:

- I understand now thanks to Darshan that by default ruby will load files in
  Encoding.default _external, but shouldn't the # encoding: iso-8859-1
  line override that?
- Should ruby be able to auto-detect a file's encoding? Is there any
  filesystem where the encoding is an attribute?
- What is my best option to 'remember' the encoding I saved the file
  in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not specifying the encoding when you read the file. You're being very careful to specify it everywhere except there, but then you're reading it with the default encoding.

```
File.open('foo.txt', "w:iso-8859-1") {|f| f << 'fòo'.force_encoding('iso-8859-1')}
File.open('foo.txt', "r:iso-8859-1") {|f| puts f.read().encoding }

# => ISO-8859-1
```

Also note that you probably mean `'fòo'.encode('iso-8859-1')` rather than `'fòo'.force_encoding('iso-8859-1')`.  The latter leaves the bytes unchanged, while the former transcodes the string.

**Update:** I'll elaborate a bit since I wasn't as clear or thorough as I could have been.

1. If you don't specify an encoding with `File.read()`, the file will be read with `Encoding.default_external`. Since you're not setting that yourself, Ruby is using a value depending on the environment it's run in.  In your Windows environment, it's IBM437; in your Cygwin environment, it's UTF-8.  So my point above was that of course that's what the encoding is; it has to be, and it has nothing to do with what bytes are contained in the file.  Ruby doesn't auto-detect encodings for you.
2. `force_encoding()` doesn't change the bytes in a string, it only changes the Encoding attached to those bytes.  If you tell Ruby "pretend this string is ISO-8859-1", then it won't transcode them when you tell it "please write this string as ISO-8859-1".  `encode()` transcodes for you, as does writing to the file if you don't trick it into *not* doing so.

Putting those together, if you have a source file in ISO-8859-1:

```
# encoding: iso-8859-1

# Write in ISO-8859-1 regardless of default_external
File.open('foo.txt', "w:iso-8859-1") {|f| f << 'fòo'}

# Read in ISO-8859-1 regardless of default_external,
#  transcoding if necessary to default_internal, if set
File.open('foo.txt', "r:iso-8859-1") {|f| puts f.read().encoding } # => ISO-8859-1

puts File.read('foo.txt').encoding # -> Whatever is specified by default_external
```

If you have a source file in UTF-8:

```
# encoding: utf-8

# Write in ISO-8859-1 regardless of default_external, transcoding from UTF-8
File.open('foo.txt', "w:iso-8859-1") {|f| f << 'fòo'}

# Read in ISO-8859-1 regardless of default_external,
#  transcoding if necessary to default_internal, if set
File.open('foo.txt', "r:iso-8859-1") {|f| puts f.read().encoding } # => ISO-8859-1

puts File.read('foo.txt').encoding # -> Whatever is specified by default_external
```

**Update 2, to answer your new questions:**

1. No, the `# encoding: iso-8859-1` line does not change `Encoding.default_external`, it only tells Ruby that the source file itself is encoded in ISO-8859-1.  Simply add

   ```
   Encoding.default_external = "iso-8859-1"
   ```

   if you expect all files that your read to be stored in that encoding.
2. No, I don't personally think Ruby should auto-detect encodings, but reasonable people can disagree on that one, and a discussion of "should it be so" seems off-topic here.
3. Personally, I use UTF-8 for everything, and in the rare circumstances that I can't control encoding, I manually set the encoding when I read the file, as demonstrated above. My source files are always in UTF-8.  If you're dealing with files that you can't control and don't know the encoding of, the [charguess gem](https://github.com/fnando/charguess) or similar would be useful.

Comment: I'm trying to demonstrate that I'm writing a iso-8859-1 string to the file, and yet when I read the file contents the encoding is wrong. Let's imagine I did not just write that file and I do not know its encoding.

Comment: @pguardiario Okay, I wasn't as thorough as I could have been in explaining what was going on.  I've just given my answer a big update.

Comment: I think I'm not being clear myself. - I use force_encoding to remove any doubt that the string might not be such encoding. I realize now that I probably introduced extra confusion. - I have found references that suggest that ruby is in fact supposed to auto-detect a file's encoding so I'm looking for something definitive one way or the other.

Comment: @pguardiario Again, `force_encoding(enc)` only ensures that Ruby will pretend the encoding is `enc`; it doesn't transcode it *to* `enc` if it wasn't already. There are gems for encoding detection, but Ruby itself doesn't do it, and reading files uses `Encoding.default_external` unless you specify an encoding.

Comment: Yes, the comment about Encoding.default _external is insightful but let's forget about force_encoding, it's not relevant to the question. I'm going to update with a better description of what I'm looking for.

Comment: @pguardiario Okay, I answered the new questions.

Comment: I decided to Marshal#dump/load the strings to file, that seems to be the best way to ensure the encoding is correct.

Comment: @pguardiario That's a good idea; a simple way to store the metadata with the data.