# CSV writes Ñ into its code form instead of its actual form

Tags: ruby, csv, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a CSV file. I checked its encoding using this:

```
File.open('C:\path\to\file\myfile.txt').read.encoding
```

and it returned the encoding as:

```
=> #<Encoding:IBM437>
```

I'm reading this CSV per row -- stripping spaces and doing other stuff. After "cleansing" it, I push it to a new file. I'm doing it like this:

```
CSV.foreach(file_read, encoding: "IBM437:UTF-8") do |r|

  # some code

  CSV.open(file_appended, "a", col_sep: "|") do |csv|
    csv << r
  end
end
```

Now my problem is, inside the CSV I'm reading, there's a word with an accented character -- **Ñ** to be exact. This character is being appended to the new file as

```
\u2564
```

Its a problem considering that the accented character is a vital part of that word, and I wanted that character to appear to the new file as-is.

Am I missing something? I tried the ff. source:destination encoding but to no avail:

- ISO-8859-1:UTF8 (and vice versa)
- ISO-8859-1:Windows-1252 (and vice versa)

Am I missing something?

Here is my ruby version, just if you'd need to know:

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using Ruby 1.9.3p392 which **has known security vulnerabilities!** You should upgrade to the latest 1.9.3 (currently 1.9.3-p448) or 2.0 as soon as possible.

Comment: Hello @AndrewMarshall. Ok I will upgrade to p448, but not to 2.0 yet since I have a rails project on the sideline that is unrelated to this ruby script that I've been tasked to do. Do you think the upgrade would somehow help solve the encoding issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line below solved my problem:

```
Encoding.default_external = "iso-8859-1"
```

It tells Ruby that the file being read is encoded in ISO-8859-1, and therefore correctly interprets the Ñ character.

Credit goes to Darshan Computing's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806543/2695310). Just look for Update #2.